# MVC5 Request.IsAuthenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

In a project using forms authentication i have an issue if you login --> stop project --> rebuild and navigate to site again. Request.IsAuthenticated will be true but the session will be nuked. I don't understand how the request can be authenticated after rebuild but session data etc is gone.

For example sitemap only renders on authenticated calls and is behind data layer and since the session is nuked the security tokens etc are missing so the requests will throw errors.

Anny ideas are welcome.

Comment: AFAIK this kind of authentication uses cookies. How do you stop the project, from within the Visual Studio? If you do it by closing the browser, does the same problem happen?

Comment: Only if i go into VS and stop the project and rebuild  and open in same browser this happens..

Comment: Right. So yes, you do need to close the browser in order to clear the cookie.